# tensorflow save and load variational auto encoder model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

I run a python script based on this [tensorflow colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/probability/blob/main/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Probabilistic_Layers_VAE.ipynb#scrollTo=ow7rfh6YLLx1) : I rewrote the colab content into a script which I run under linux on a server with 2 GPUs --> this runs smoothly. I refer to the colab code implementation in this post.

I would like now to modify the script in order to practice saving and loading the model.

**two models**

"Two models" are used to illustrate the training : (1) the whole `variational encoder model`, variable named `vae` in the script, which is made of an encoder and a decoder part, and (2) the `decoder model only`, created with the Functional API and variable named `decoder` in the script.

I quote the implementation for the encoder

```
encoder = tfk.Sequential([
    tfkl.InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape),
    tfkl.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(x, tf.float32) - 0.5),
    tfkl.Conv2D(base_depth, 5, strides=1,
                padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2D(base_depth, 5, strides=2,
                padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2D(2 * base_depth, 5, strides=1,
                padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2D(2 * base_depth, 5, strides=2,
                padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2D(4 * encoded_size, 7, strides=1,
                padding='valid', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Flatten(),
    tfkl.Dense(tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(encoded_size),
               activation=None),
    tfpl.MultivariateNormalTriL(
        encoded_size,
        activity_regularizer=tfpl.KLDivergenceRegularizer(prior)),
])
```

the decoder

```
decoder = tfk.Sequential([
    tfkl.InputLayer(input_shape=[encoded_size]),
    tfkl.Reshape([1, 1, encoded_size]),
    tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(2 * base_depth, 7, strides=1,
                         padding='valid', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(2 * base_depth, 5, strides=1,
                         padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(2 * base_depth, 5, strides=2,
                         padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(base_depth, 5, strides=1,
                         padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(base_depth, 5, strides=2,
                         padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2DTranspose(base_depth, 5, strides=1,
                         padding='same', activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu),
    tfkl.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=5, strides=1,
                padding='same', activation=None),
    tfkl.Flatten(),
    tfpl.IndependentBernoulli(input_shape, tfd.Bernoulli.logits),
])
```

the whole variational autoencoder

```
vae = tfk.Model(inputs=encoder.inputs,
                outputs=decoder(encoder.outputs[0]))
```

Illustration goes as follow, (1) we take ten digits and apply the whole encoding+decoding chain on it to vizualize the reconstruction. We use the `vae` model.

```
# We'll just examine ten random digits.
x = next(iter(eval_dataset))[0][:10]
xhat = vae(x)
```

(2) we sample 10 "never-seen-before" digits from our prior distribution, and apply the decoder to obtain realistic "hand-written" digits

```
# Now, let's generate ten never-before-seen digits.
z = prior.sample(10)
xtilde = decoder(z)
```

**my question : how to implement saving and loading the models**

This is my code change for saving the `vae` modelL

```
vae.save('saved_vae')
```

which produces this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "probabilistic_vae.py", line 103, in <module>
    vae.save('saved_vae')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2146, in save
    signatures, options, save_traces)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/save.py", line 150, in save_model
    signatures, options, save_traces)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py", line 91, in save
    model, filepath, signatures, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1228, in save_and_return_nodes
    _build_meta_graph(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1399, in _build_meta_graph
    return _build_meta_graph_impl(obj, signatures, options, meta_graph_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 1336, in _build_meta_graph_impl
    checkpoint_graph_view)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/signature_serialization.py", line 99, in find_function_to_export
    functions = saveable_view.list_functions(saveable_view.root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py", line 164, in list_functions
    self._serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2813, in _list_functions_for_serialization
    Model, self)._list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 3086, in _list_functions_for_serialization
    .list_functions_for_serialization(serialization_cache))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/base_serialization.py", line 93, in list_functions_for_serialization
    fns = self.functions_to_serialize(serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 74, in functions_to_serialize
    serialization_cache).functions_to_serialize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 90, in _get_serialized_attributes
    serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/model_serialization.py", line 57, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    serialization_cache))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 99, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    functions = save_impl.wrap_layer_functions(self.obj, serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 149, in wrap_layer_functions
    original_fns = _replace_child_layer_functions(layer, serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 277, in _replace_child_layer_functions
    serialization_cache).functions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 90, in _get_serialized_attributes
    serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/layer_serialization.py", line 99, in _get_serialized_attributes_internal
    functions = save_impl.wrap_layer_functions(self.obj, serialization_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/save_impl.py", line 197, in wrap_layer_functions
    fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1233, in get_concrete_function
    concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 1213, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 760, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3066, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3463, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3308, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1007, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 668, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 994, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
AttributeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/distribution_layer.py:1261 __call__  *
        return self._kl_divergence_fn(distribution_a)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/distribution_layer.py:1380 _fn  **
        kl = kl_divergence_fn(distribution_a, distribution_b_)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/distribution_layer.py:1364 kl_divergence_fn
        distribution_a.log_prob(z) - distribution_b.log_prob(z),
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:401 __getattr__
        self.__getattribute__(name)

    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'log_prob'
```

**Beyond this error, I would like to know if my implementation and my approach is correct.**

I do the same for the decoder only

```
decoder_rec=keras.models.load_model('decoder_saved')

# Now, let's generate ten never-before-seen digits.
z = prior.sample(10)
xtilde = decoder_rec(z)
assert isinstance(xtilde, tfd.Distribution)
```

Same thing, I would like to know if my approach is correct : saving and loading separately weights/model corresponding to the "whole vae" and to the "decoder only".

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the line producing the error (here `vae.save('saved_vae')`) is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 1):

partial answer to my own question--

Probabilistic layers seems not to be possibly saved with `keras.models.save_model()` only weights can be saved and reloaded on a model created with the Functional API.

I could do so successfully on the encoder with

```
decoder.save_weights('saved_decoder')
```

then, separately in another script

```
decoder.load_weights('saved_decoder')

# Now, let's generate ten never-before-seen digits.
z = prior.sample(10)
xtilde = decoder(z)
```

loads the weights correctly.

I still don't know if this is doable with the whole vae model as well, which is a combination of the encoder and decoder and so not purely using the Functional API, and if their is another better way to do.